# Successfully connected to Asana but doesnt post task

Tags: asana

Im trying to post a task on asana through c#. The Json string that im sending is:

```
{"workspace":1234567890123,"data": {"name":"Buy eggs","notes":"Testing"}}
```

and the response I'm getting is:

> {"data":{"id":123439968,"created_at":"2015-01-14T21:35:31.288Z","modified_at":"2015-01-14T21:35:31.288Z","name":"Buy
>   eggs","notes":"Testing","completed":false,"assignee_status":"upcoming","completed_at":null,"due_on":null,"workspace":{"id":12345678901234,"name":"CompanyName"},"num_hearts":0,"assignee":null,"parent":null,"hearts":[],"followers":[{"id":12345689965587,"name":"MyName"}],"projects":[],"tags":[],"hearted":false}}

But when I log into asana the task isn't there, what do I do?

Answer (score 0):

The task has been created, but since it's not assigned to anyone or in any projects, it's not going to show up in any lists. The follower you added ("MyName") should be able to search for the task, but in general you want to specify a project to add to, or at the very least an assignee (so it shows up in their "My Tasks").